# How to correctly add meta tags to custom menu items?

Tags: 7, meta-tags

I want to be able to use the meta tag module for everything my site, but currently I have no idea how to add meta tags to custom pages. For example, I have this page:

```
function mymodule_menu() 
{ 
    $items = array();
    $items['home'] = array(
      'title' => 'Home',
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_home_page',
      'access callback' => TRUE,
    );
    return $items;
}

function mymodule()
{
    $o = '';
    $o .= 'hello world';
    return $o;
}
```

Such a page doesn't get meta tags as it is a custom page. What is the best way to get meta tags on the page in this case? Or what is wrong with my strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this manually by using [drupal_add_html_head();](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7) in your menu's callback function

```
<?php

function mymodule_home_page() {

  $element = array(
    '#tag' => 'meta', 
    '#attributes' => array( 
      'name' => 'custom meta info', 
      'content' => 'test content',
      'attributes' => 'D7',
    ),
  );
  drupal_add_html_head($element, 'Test');

  return 'hello';
} 
?>
```

or some modules will allow you to add custom paths.